# Sich umsehen vs. (he)rumgucken

Tags: synonym

Sind die beiden vollständige Synonyme oder gibt es in der Tat irgendwelche Unterschiede, vor allem bezüglich des Kontexts?

1. Im Laden *Wir wollten halt rumgucken*  or  *Wir wollten uns halt umsehen*
2. *Ich sehe mich nach einer netten Wohnung um*  or *Ich gucke nach einer netten Wohnung rum* (Kommt mir eher falsch vor)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Die sehr ausführliche Antwort von Hubert Schölnast ist dahingehend zu ergänzen, dass

> sich umgucken / herumgucken

in jedem Kontext umgangssprachlich und in verschiedenen Aussprachen (von guggen bis kucken) regional gebräuchlich ist, während

> sich umsehen

hoch- und schriftsprachlich ist.

> sich umschauen

ist in Süddeutschland und Österreich das (über)regionale Synonym für "sich umgucken", kann aber auch in einem Text auftauchen, ohne besonders aufzufallen.

Answer (score 4):

Zumindest in Österreich (und möglicherweise in Bayern, aber darüber kann ich nichts Genaueres sagen), ist die Antwort klar. Hier wird nämlich nicht geguckt. Es gibt:

> Sich umsehen
>   Sich umschauen

Die Variante »sich umgucken« ist hier ungebräuchlich. Das liegt daran, dass das Verb »gucken« samt allen Abwandlungen in Österreich ungebräuchlich ist und stattdessen nur »sehen« und »schauen« verwendet werden.

Wichtig ist zu wissen, dass »umsehen«, »umschauen« und auch »umgucken« reflexive Verben sind, also nur zusammen mit »mich«, »dich«, »sich«, »uns« und »euch« auftreten können.

Dein Beispiel müsste also so lauten:

> Ich gucke **mich** nach einer netten Wohnung um.

Außerdem gibt es einen Unterschied zwischen »rum« (das ist die Kurzform von »herum«) und »um«. »Herumgucken« (und daher auch »rumgucken«) ist nämlich nicht reflexiv. Man kann zwar »herumgucken«, aber nicht »sich herumgucken«:

> Jakob sah in der Gegend herum.
>   Jakob schaute in der Gegend herum.
>   Jakob guckte in der Gegend herum.

Das bedeutet: Jakob ließ seinen Blick über die Landschaft schweifen, um einen Gesamteindruck von seiner Umgebung zu erhalten, aber ohne mit seinen Blicken ein besonderes Ziel zu verfolgen oder einzelnen Details besondere Aufmerksamkeit zu schenken.

aber

> Jakob sah sich in der Gegend um.
>   Jakob schaute sich in der Gegend um.
>   Jakob guckte sich in der Gegend um.

Das bedeutet etwas anderes: Jakob betrachtete einzelne Details in seiner Umgebung, um festzustellen, ob diese ihm bei der Erfüllung seines Vorhabens dienlich sein können.

Wenn man in einem Geschäft (auch das Wort »Laden« wird in Österreich eher selten verwendet) die Waren ohne besondere Kaufabsicht betrachtet, und sich nur einen Überblick über das Angebot verschaffen will, ist das in österreichischem Hochdeutsch:

> Ich sehe mich hier um.
>   Ich schaue mich hier um.

Häufig wird zwischen »hier« und »um« auch das Wort »nur« eingefügt: *Ich sehe/schaue mich hier nur um.*

Wenn man auf Wohnungssuche ist, sagt man:

> Ich sehe mich nach einer Wohnung um.
>   Ich schaue mich nach einer Wohnung um.

Ob man sich in Deutschland auch umgucken kann (egal ob in einem Geschäft oder nach einer Wohnung), weiß ich nicht genau, ich glaube aber, dass man dieses Wort auch in diesem Zusammenhang verwenden kann. Aber ich vermute auch, dass das als minderwertiger Stil angesehen wird, was in Österreich auf »sich umschauen« aber nicht zutrifft.

---

### *sehen*, *schauen* und *gucken* als mögliche Synonyme

»Sehen« und »schauen« werde meist als Synonyme verwendet, aber nicht immer. Ich bin mit der Verwendung von »gucken« nur wenig vertraut, aber ich glaube, dass alles, was ich hier über »schauen« sage, auch auf »gucken« zutrifft, außer ich weise ausdrücklich auf das Gegenteil hin. In allfälligen Kommentaren zu meiner Antwort wird man sicher nachlesen können, ob das tatsächlich zutrifft.

Wenn man etwas mit den Augen wahrnimmt, kann *sehen* nicht durch *schauen* (und auch nicht durch *gucken*) ersetzt werden:

> Ich sehe da einen Fleck auf deiner Wange.

Wenn man etwas betrachtet, sind »sich ansehen« und »sich anschauen« austauschbar:

> Ich sehe mir gerade einen Film an.
>   Ich schaue mir gerade einen Film an.

Auch im Fall von *etwas/jemanden ansehen* kann man schauen:

> Der Ermittler sah den Verdächtigen mit strengem Blick an.
>   Der Ermittler schaute den Verdächtigen mit strengem Blick an.

Wenn der Vorgang der optischen Wahrnehmung thematisiert wird, kann man nur *sehen* verwenden:

> Ich bauche eine Brille, ich sehe schlecht.

»Aussehen« kann durch »ausschauen« ersetzt werden, so etwas wie »ausgucken« (zumindest in derselben Bedeutung wie »aussehen«) gibt es aber nicht:

> Du siehst krank aus, leg dich ins Bett.
>   Du schaust krank aus, leg dich ins Bett.

Es gibt aber auch Fälle, wo man nur »schauen« und »gucken«, nicht aber »sehen« verwenden kann:

> Schau nicht so blöd!
>   Guck nicht so doof!

Oder auch

> Was guckst du?
>   Wieso schaust du so?

Answer (score 1):

Der Gebrauch des Wortes *gucken* ist regional begrenzt. Ich habe einen Bekannten aus Norddeutschland, der mir sagte, dass *gucken* in seiner Region (Lübeck) nicht Teil des normalen Wortschatzes ist.

Ich würde *gucken* eher als synonym für *glotzen* sehen.

Es kann ähnlich gebraucht werden.

z. B.:

> Glotz nicht so = Guck nicht so
>
> und
>
> Glotz mich nicht so an = Guck mich
> nicht so an

Was beiden gemeinsam ist, ist erstens der etwas herbere Tonfall im Vergleich zu sehen.

> Vgl. sieh mich nicht so an.

*Gucken, glotzen* und *starren* beziehen sich direkter auf die Benutzung der Glotzen (Augen), während *sehen* auch indirekt benutzt wird. Wie z. B. *ich habe ihn gesehen.*

*Ich habe ihn geglotzt* oder *ich habe ihn geguckt* geht nicht, während *ich habe ihn an-gesehen* bzw. *an-geguckt* oder *an-geglotzt* machbar ist.

Der Unterschied zwischen *gesehen* und *angesehen* ist der der Absicht.

Jemand kann durch das Blickfeld laufen und man sieht ihn.

Aber jemand kann durch das Blickfeld laufen, man wird aufmerksam und sieht ihn an bzw. starrt ihn für eine längere Zeit an.

> glotzen = gucken = starren → aktiv etwas anschauen
>
> sehen = wahrnehmen → passiv etwas gewahr werden