# Is there any differences between “gucken” and “schauen”?

Tags: difference

*"Gucken* means *to look* or *to peek* and *schauen* means *to see.* Both meanings are almost the same.

For example, consider the sentence:

> Ich würde gern eine DVD gucken.

Can I use *schauen* instead of *gucken* here? And what’s the difference?

Comment: Related: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/36810/sieh-mal-vs-guck-mal/36821#36821

Comment: Also related: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/22676/sich-umsehen-vs-herumgucken/

Comment: Imo 'gucken' is almost baby-talk and not appropriate for something as lengthy as a DVD.

Comment: @TaW; if you got this impression you certainly never went to a region where *gucken* is common (see map in my answer). Also, with all respect, using "baby-talk", or "inappropriate language" is actually quite rude to people who speak dialect.

Comment: Your map is not relevant for this question. 'Eine DVD angucken' would mean to have a glimpe at the cover, not to spend 1-2h watching it. And dialect is obviously irrelevant as well as OP doesn't ask about it. But of course I didn't mean to be rude, just keeping things straight. I speak dialect as well but would not advice learners of German to adopt our local oddities.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There is no difference in meaning but *[gucken](https://dwds.de/wb/gucken)* is used colloquially in the south-west or *kucken* in the north. Bavarian or Alemannic dialects do not use it.

For the regional distribution see the [Atlas der Altagssprache](http://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/r10-f13h/):

[image]

Comment: This map doesn’t really match my (limited) personal experience: being from North Germany, “gucken” strikes me as mostly obsolete, and “schauen” or “sehen” as much more common.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: this map depicts the results of a questionnaire answered by 20.000 people in 2013. More background [here](http://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/runde-10/).

Comment: @Konrad I think “als Aufforderung” and (on the page linked to) “jemanden auf etwas aufmerksam machen” is important here. I’m not German, and not even particularly proficient in German, but while I can’t recall hearing people using _kucken/gucken_ as a regular verb very often, I have definitely heard both _Kuck mal hier_ and _Schau mal hier_ quite commonly in regular conversation.

Comment: Die Aufforderung ist aber gar nicht die Frage!

Comment: @TaW: und genau deshalb mein erster Satz! Wenn Du eine bessere Quelle zur regionalen Verteilung von *gucken, kucken, schauen, schaugen, luege,...* hast, dann würde ich mich auf Deine Antwort sehr freuen.

Comment: I am a German-speaking South African and grew up with "gucken" for everyday use. The German that is used among descendants of German settlers (which is now quickly dying out) has a few older words that aren't in general use in Germany anymore. (But of course South Africa is not on the above map :-)

Answer (score 9):

The meaning is the same, but the two verbs are used in different frequency in different regions.

I live in the south of the German spoken area, in Austria, not far away from Vienna. And here nobody who grew up here would use the word "gucken". When ever you hear someone using this word in Austria, you know this person is either a German tourist or a German immigrant.

This is not absolutely true for people younger than 25 who live in bigger towns like Vienna, Graz and Linz. Lots of them also use "gucken" when talking with their friends, but "schauen" when talking with older people.

In the north of Germany the verb "gucken" is used much more frequent. I believe (without knowing for sure), that in Köln, Hamburg and Berlin "gucken" is used even more often than "schauen" (by speaker of any age).

Comment: *I believe (without knowing for sure), that in (...) Berlin "gucken" is used even more often than "schauen"* Your belief is right, yet not strong enough. It is not exactly the opposite from Austria, but "schauen" is quite rarely used. If someone says "schauen", it is probably a tourist, an immigrant - or (s)he is influenced by hearing it from many immigrants.

Comment: @VolkerLandgraf: in Berlin there also is *kieken*, which supposedly is not related to *kucken*

Comment: @Takkat: Da haste in jewisser Weise recht, aba ooch ick als jebürt'jer Berlina empfinde "kieken" nur als Dialekt-Aussprache von det hochdeutsche "gucken" und nich als völlich andret Wort wie "schauen" ;-)

Comment: @VolkerLandgraf: :) die Idee kommt von [Pfeifer](https://dwds.de/wb/gucken)

Comment: The fact that "gucken" becomes common in Austria arises from television, Internet and - last but not least - children's books. Austria's contribution to children's books is close to zero, so whenever I read a book to my children, I use "gucken", because all these books are written in Germany. In everyday usage, I would never use "gucken", always "schauen".

Comment: @rexkogitans: It is hard for Austrian authors to publish anything in Austrian German. Only some detective stories playing at Austrian locations are published in Austrian German. The argument of publishers (even Austrian publishers): "We can sell a book in Austrian German only in Austria (8.9M residents). A book in German German can be sold in Austria and also in Germany (81.4M residents) (sum = 90,3M). Also lots of magazines are imported from Germany, so there are more German magazines available in Austria than Austrian magazines. Austrian German is slowly fading away.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast just because of some words like "Karotte" and "schauen"? I am not talking about Austrian dialect, but of written language.

Comment: @rexkogitans: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Österreichisches_Deutsch Daraus ein Zitat: »Das österreichische Deutsch unterscheidet sich in Teilen des Wortschatzes, grammatikalischen Besonderheiten, der Schreibweise und auch in der Aussprache von jenem Hochdeutsch, das in Deutschland durch den Duden kodifiziert ist.«

Comment: @rexkogitans Try looking up Thomas Brezina or Christine Nöstlinger and rethink your statement.

Answer (score 3):

As it was pointed out, the use of schauen/gucken is dialect-dependant. Yet in your specific sentence I would use "ansehen" or "anschauen" if you mean that you want to watch the movie that is on the DVD.

I'm not german, though. I might be wrong...

Stimmt's oder habe ich recht, Leute? :-)

Comment: You could use ansehen or anschauen as well, but the other verbs are more commonly used with friends.

Comment: I think "Eine DVD schauen" is fine and unambiguous. "Eine DVD anschauen/ansehen" is correct but could also mean *looking at the DVD* depending on the context.

Answer (score 3):

In some regions of Germany it is the same. But here “Schauen” is more cultivated than gucken. Gucken would rather fit for a simple cartoon or entertaining movie like a soap, but not for a sensitive film like Schindler’s list. That’s why it’s called Tagesschau, I  wouldn’t say: Ich gucke die  “Tagesschau” but: Ich gucke die  “Wochenshow” in ZDF as it is a show.

Answer (score 1):

I know no difference in the meaning. Your example: you could do so.

The difference comes in the percentage of usage. The people I talk to seem to use "schauen" instead of "gucken" (not always, just most time).

So I assume it is somewhat area specific, because "sch" and the hard "g" fit differently well into a dialect.

There is also the idiom "schau mal einer guck" - which simply means that the speaker is (positivly) surprised what is visible and uses a pleonasm.

Comment: "schau mal einer guck" fehlt da nicht ein t bei guckt? Ich bin mir nicht sicher, da ich die Redewendung nicht kenne.

Comment: Ich kenne sie witzigerweise genau andersherum: "guck mal einer schau" - aber auch hier ohne "t" am Ende, da es sich um den Imperativ handelt.

Comment: @Iris Nein, das t gehört da gar nicht rein. Das ist eine feste Redewendung, die nicht unbedingt grammatikalisch 100% den Regeln entsprechen muss.