# Is there some relative to Dutch word "kijken" in German?

Tags: dialect, vocabulary, loanword

Inspired by [this question](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/49843/is-there-any-differences-between-gucken-and-schauen), I wonder if there is also some German relative (dialect or general) of Dutch word "kijken" for to watch or look at something.

I think for example I saw or heard somewhere a comment about "kieken", is this used?

---

An example where kijken is used

```
Wil je met me voetbal kijken
```

which google translates to

```
Willst du mit mir Fußball gucken?
```

Comment: Having zero knowledge about Dutch - could you please provide explantory examples how "kijken" is used and what meanings are common? Otherwise you need an answerer that has a deep understanding about both Dutch and German.

Comment: Gucken/Kucken. But "kieken" is only used in some parts of the country, usually those not far from the Dutch border (e.g. Münsterland, etc.). <g>

Comment: Possibly related words in other Germanic languages: _kige_, _kikke_ (Danish), _kika_ (Swedish and Norwegian), _keek_ (Scottish), _peek_ (English).

Comment: Yep I know. Kika in Swedish especially reminds of kijken.

Answer (score 11):

The German for *kijken* is

> kucken

sometimes (especially in the South) also written like

> gucken

Both is standard German, and you can find both forms registered in *Der Duden* (most authoritative reference dictionary for German).

*Kieken*, in contrast, is a Northern dialectal form of *kucken*, and of course it is so to say the bridge to *kijken*.

There are many common phrases with *kucken*, e.g.

> Kuck mal an! / Kuck mal einer an!  / Ja da guck an!

meaning something like: "*Oh, that's indeed surprising!" In Swabian dialect (in the South-West) this would be: *Jo do guck naa!*.

> Da kuckst du, was?

"That's surprising for you, isn't it?"

> Mal kucken...

meaning something like: "Okay, I don't know yet, but we will see what brings the future; or simply: "Let's see."

> Was kuckst du?

a stereotypical bully phrase of oriental street gang members who want to intimidate somebody who dared to look at them. Pronunciation is then typically more like *Wuss kuckstu!*

Also a person can

> dumm aus der Wäsche kucken

i.e. look stupid after taken by unpleasant surprise by something.

Comment: Grimm knows everything: http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?lemma=kiken

Comment: @DavidVogt Wow "kiken", that is so cool.

Comment: my granny (speaking "plattdeutsch") was using a similar: https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/kieken , also known in Berlin afaik

Comment: Isn't this less like a "bridge" over something dividing but a very gentle transition of really one and the same word on the dialect continuum? Cross the Ems eastward and kiecken is still around you?

Comment: @CarstenS Hm... yes... you might be right. I will change this.

Comment: The 'stereotype' angle seems either superfluous or needs expansion. If the latter, another 'oriental' form would be *Vos guggsd'n?*, found around Chemnitz… (with the last consonant almost swallowed with Xhosa like clicking sound)

Comment: What does "oriental" mean in this context?

Comment: @fdb  People culturally attached to countries of what was once called "Orient" before Edward Said explained to us that this was a projection.

Comment: @LangLangC  I struggle producing a Xhosa like clicking sound for the last consonant (I suppose the 'n'). Could you post an audio?

Comment: It is before the n, and then after the n follows a sound like the speakers swallow their glottis and epiglottis whole while squeaking a *very* faint schwa. Just trying to imitate this both I almost have to puke. Most extreme example was a hool from that area. I will not ask him directly, but will try to carry a hot mike next time I expect to 'meet' that particular individual or his friends of Saxonian soccer operas.

Comment: @LangLangC  So something like *vos guggsd-URGH*? I am acquainted to Saxonian (lived in Leipzig some time) but this is anyway unimaginable for me.

Answer (score 8):

There is a related question on StackExchange [Is there any differences between “Gucken” and “Schauen”?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/49843/is-there-any-differences-between-gucken-and-schauen).

One of the answers contains this plot from [Atlas der Alltagssprache](http://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/r10-f13h/), which shows how people formulate a call like "Look (there)!"

[image: Geographical Distribution of schauen/gucken/...]

Comment: Why does the Cologne area not have "Lur (ens)"?

Answer (score 5):

In the Berlin dialect there is actually "kieken" [ki​ː​​kən] as form of high german "gucken" and I guess that is a heritage of its low german roots. It has the tendency to swallow its surrounding morphemes, e.g. "Da kiekste, wa?" ("Da guckst Du, nicht wahr?") or "Kiekstn so?" ("Was guckst Du so?").

Answer (score 2):

You ask whether there is a German "relative" (i.e., cognate) of the Dutch word. Yes, it is the North German "kieken". According to the experts on etymology, "kieken" is not cognate with "gucken". Their similarity is coincidental.

https://www.dwds.de/wb/gucken

Comment: "... nicht verwandten und ebenfalls etymologisch ungeklärten ..." Das sind zwei Aussagen die logisch nicht nebeneinander stehen können.

Comment: @vectory: /i:/ neben /u/ ist lautgeschichtlich nicht zu erklären.

Comment: I~Ü~U are close, individually. You can hear *Tüsch* for *Tisch* in certain regions, or read *zu Hülf!*~*Hilfe* known from Erika Fuchs, and what about *Feuer*, *fire* and, I guess, eventually *Fuir*. U>Ü is a common grammatical alternation, e.g. in Buch>Bücher. So one could posit guck>kuck>Küken>kieken. The only Küken I know would be "chick", "'Cognate to Dutch kuiken, English chicken. A related form is Middle High German kuchil, whence now obsolete Küchlein." "[kuiken] from Middle Dutch kuken, kiken, originally from Proto-Germanic *kiukīną. A modern variant form is kieken." (c) Wiktionary

Comment: Wiktionary makes the more agreeable claim "Compare also German gucken, kucken, which need not be originally related, but has probably been influenced by kieken."